# "scale to bounds" missing in blender 2.9?

Tags: scale, object-mode

In blender 2.8 there was a search result when hitting space that allowed me to scale an object to perfectly fit within a specific size, called "scale to bounds" I believe. in 2.9 this appears to be missing or I can't find it- can this still be done in 2.9? it was very useful for me and I still need the feature for the stuff I need to create.

Comment: I think scale to bounds if from the 3DPrint addon. Activate it in the preferences.

Comment: that is correct- thanks. you should post that as an answer so i can mark this answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Scale to bounds"* is from the *"3DPrint"* addon. Activate it in the preferences.